# Binary Sequence Combination Generator, in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary

Code works, but feels very brute force, suggestions?

Goal of the code is to supply an array length, and then as fast as possible generate all possible unique binary combinations with that array length.

**CODE:**

```
class Array
  def sequence(i = 0, *a)
    return [a] if i == size
    self[i].map {|x|
      sequence(i+1, *(a + [x]))
    }.inject([]) {|m, x| m + x}
  end
end


[(0..1),(0..1),(0..1)].sequence
```

**OUTPUTS:**

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Since you've just taken this code from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3332, what would you rather it did?

Comment: This code does not work, because output is not a list of permutations.

Comment: @Krzysztof Chrobak how is that not a list of permutations?

Comment: @dominikh - permutation should be injective, and the values in each sublist of output appear more than once. However, Its possible that I misunderstood the purpose of this code.

Comment: @ DownVoter,VoteToClose: Please express your thoughts on what is wrong with the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

permutation and repeated_permutation are built in, so you can do:

```
def sequence(n)
  [0, 1].repeated_permutation(n).to_a
end
p sequence(3) #=>[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: This is by far the more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 2):

"All unique binary combinations" with n bits is nothing but (0...2**n), so the only task is to efficiently convert from an integer to its binary representation, and the following is a solution that does not rely on string generation/manipulation:

```
def sequence(n)
  ret = []
  (2**n).times do |number|
    ret << []
    (n - 1).downto(0) do |bit|
      ret.last << number[bit]
    end
  end

  ret
end

sequence(3) 
# => [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Or, if you prefer a version more oriented on list operations, this is pretty much the same:

```
def sequence(n)
  (0...2**n).map {|number|
    (1..n).map {|bit|
      number[n-bit]
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: Instead of `..foo - 1`, use `...foo` :-)

Comment: @blunders Now you're confusing me :) What Marc-André recommended was to use `a...b` instead of `a..b-1`, note the three dots, which excludes the final element. They both do the exact same thing though.

Comment: Indeed, it wasn't a bug, just a styling issue. `(2**n).times.map` would do the job too, btw. Also, it might be even clearer to use `n.downto(1).map` to avoid the substraction later on. In any case, this solution works and is quite readable.

Comment: @dominikh: Bug was on my end, only notice the remove of "-1" and not the change of ".." to "..." - which was clearly on my end, and I should have just re-downloaded the code after the update instead of manually looking and the changes. Thanks for following up on my confusion! :-)